# How to resize a Photoimage displayed from web url

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage, Tk,Label
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

imgurl="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/312/312/kn7sdjk0/mobile/w/h/q/c20-rmx3063-realme-original-imagfxfzay72jqvh.jpeg?q=70"
root= Tk()
data=urlopen(imgurl)
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=data.read())
lbl=Label(root,image=img)
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Above code displays me image from a web url in tkinter label i want do change the width and height of the image how can i do that

Thank you for giving any kind of help

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass it onto `Image.open()` to get an `Image` object and after getting it, you can `resize` and do all what you want:

```
data  = urlopen(imgurl)

img   = Image.open(data).resize((w,h),Image.ANTIALIAS) # w is width and h is height
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 

lbl   = Label(root,image=imgtk)
```

Or if you want to split it into two lines(no real reason to):

```
img = Image.open(data)
img = img.resize((w,h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

`Image.ANTIALIAS` is the supersampling to be applied, so that resized image will be not have *all* jagged edges.